Swift User Struct Error: Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
I am building a profile page and I am trying to make the profile picture save even after the user signs out.
This is my user struct:
struct User: Codable {
    var uid: String
    var email: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var signUpDate: Date
    var bio: String
    var interests: [String]
    var profilePictureURL: URL?
}

This is my profile page view(the part that is causing the error):
struct ProfileView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userViewModel: UserViewModel
    @State private var bio = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "bio") ?? "Car enthusiast | Eco-friendly driver | Developer"
    @State private var interests = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "interests") ?? "Travel, Coding, Green Living"
    @State private var isEditingBio = false
    @State private var isEditingInterests = false
    @State private var isEditingProfile = false
    @State private var selectedImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            if let selectedImage = selectedImage {
                if let imageData = selectedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(imageData, forKey: "profileImage")
                }
            }
        }
    }
   init(userViewModel: UserViewModel) {
    self.userViewModel = userViewModel
    if let imageData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "profileImage"),
       let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
        _selectedImage = State(initialValue: image)
    } else {
        // Initialize with a default image if no profile image is found
        _selectedImage = State(initialValue: UIImage(systemName: "person.circle.fill")!)
    }
}

The error is occuring at the second init statement and the error is:
Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
I have tried looking at other solutions on stack overflow but I don't really understand them. I also tried initializing the other values by inputting a user:user parameter and then doing let uid=user.uid and so on and so forth for the other properties. I am confused on how to fix this. Thank you for any help!

Your updated code completely changes your question. Please update your question and its title to reflect the updated code and your updated issue.

Error show in second init is because you are not intialize userViewModel in it. So all you need to do is move code from second init to init(userViewModel::
init(userViewModel: UserViewModel) {
    self.userViewModel = userViewModel
    if let imageData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "profileImage"),
       let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
        _selectedImage = State(initialValue: image)
    } else {
        // Initialize with a default image if no profile image is found
        _selectedImage = State(initialValue: UIImage(systemName: "person.circle.fill")!)
    }
}

Also, you should use onChange modifer to observe change of @State instead of using didSet. To interact with UserDefaults in SwiftUI you should use @AppStorage too.
struct ProfileView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userViewModel: UserViewModel
    @AppStorage("bio") private var bio: String = "Car enthusiast | Eco-friendly driver | Developer" // <- change to @AppStorage
    @AppStorage("bio") private var interests: String = "Travel, Coding, Green Living" // <- change to @AppStorage
    @State private var isEditingBio = false
    @State private var isEditingInterests = false
    @State private var isEditingProfile = false
    @State private var selectedImage: UIImage?
    
    init(userViewModel: UserViewModel) {
        self.userViewModel = userViewModel
        if let imageData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "profileImage"),
           let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
            _selectedImage = State(initialValue: image)
        } else {
            // Initialize with a default image if no profile image is found
            _selectedImage = State(initialValue: UIImage(systemName: "person.circle.fill")!)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ...
            .onChange(of: selectedImage) { newValue in
                if let selectedImage = newValue {
                    if let imageData = selectedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(imageData, forKey: "profileImage")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}


I did this but the profile picture still did not save. I removed the second init statement and put it all in the first one. Check the question I edited it.

@AppleDev3 Checkout my updated answer
